# Java RegEx combine patterns in any form

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match some legal documents links. I've gone fare enough but I think I'm missing something. This is my work for now:

```
(\d( )?)?(([[a-zA-Z]\.])+?) ([0-9]+?)\b:([0-9]+?)?\b
```

I have a base construction witch I can match:

? = optional

```
number/space?/string/space/number/:/number
```

But now I want to optionally match any combination of the fallowing:

```
-/number
,/space/number
,/space/number/-/number
```

This is my best match:

```
(\d( )?)?(([[a-zA-Z]\.])+?) ([0-9]+?)\b:([0-9]+?)(, [0-9]+?)?(-[0-9]+?)?(, ([0-9]+?)-([0-9]+?)?)?\b
```

I can match this:

```
8 Law 84:145, 252-320
```

But not this:

```
8 Law 84:145, 252-320, 458, 517-665
```

Comment: It is not clear what you need to get in the end. What capture groups do you intend to get? Is the first number really optional? It is not acc. to your formula. See [the regex I came up with](https://regex101.com/r/QzPDVa/2).

Comment: Is this java regex??

Comment: Yes, just when defining a pattern using Java string literals, backslashes must be doubled.

Comment: Yes it works, sorry. Thanks! Create an answer please.

Comment: Great, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\d+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)((?:-\d+|,\s\d+(?:-\d+)?)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QzPDVa/2)

The main part I added is `((?:-\d+|,\s\d+(?:-\d+)?)*)` that matches and captures into a group 0 or more sequences of:

- `-\d+` - a hyphen and 1+ digits
- `|`  - or
- `,\s\d+(?:-\d+)?` - comma, whitespace, 1+ digits, and then an optional sequence of `-` and 1+ digits.

Do not forget to double backslashes in the Java string literal inside the code.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!